# Smart Card Reader, RealTime Event

Tags: c#, wpf

I just received my new toy, a smart card reader, I was able to connect and get the UID and then read/write data to my card, is there a way to make an EventHandler to monitor the transaction without using thread? I am using winscard.dll.

Comment: You probably won't have any native handler for a read/write ongoing operation. That being said, a tiny bit of googling brings up [this code project page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16653/A-Smart-Card-Framework-for-NET). Maybe you can use the marshalling part to monitor your read/write operations. (edit: i assumed you wanted to have a progress bar)

Comment: Thanks @Kilazur, I just want to monitor whenever a card is connected to my reader. Last night I just created a separate thread, however I was just thinking if maybe there is a handler that would automatically trigger an event whenever a card is connected just like in zkSoftware biometrics OnFinger event. But then I will take a look at this link. Thanks by the way.